# Why do min-height property which is applied to the outer div increase the height of the inner div?

Tags: css

HTML :

```
<div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
div {
  background: #BCCF03;
  min-height: 300px
}

div div {
background: #5DAF33;
height: 22px
}
```

**[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qqmgbkh6/)**

As we can see, `min-height` is applied only to the outer `div`, but it increases the height of the inner `div` too. Why does it happen? `min-height` isn't an inherited property.

Comment: `min-height` is being applied to all `<div>`s, not just the parent / outer-most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the way you wrote your css.  Give the divs classes and it wont happen.

HTML :

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.outer {
  background: #BCCF03;
  min-height: 300px
}

.inner {
background: #5DAF33;
height: 22px
}
```

To further elaborate, you are setting all divs min-height to 300px.  This will be the case on all divs unless it is explicitly set afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

The inside thing is a div hence, having 300 min-width as you gave it in the first css block. Min-width overrides width. Just give inner div a "display:inline"

```
div {
  background: #BCCF03;
  min-height: 300px
}

div div {
background: #5DAF33;
height: 22px;display:inline;
}
```

so it remains 22 width instead of min-width value.